# Eclipse CPP and GNU following these instructions

Tags: eclipse, opengl, build, precompiled

I am trying to build a given a precompiled header to create a static library. I do not use the eclipse ide (I use VC++10) and I need help understanding these instructions:

How to build GLUS:

1. Install Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers and a GNU Compiler Collection for your operating system.
2. Extract this ZIP file and set the workspace-cpp folder as your Eclipse workspace.
3. Import each folder as a separate, existing project.
4. Set the build configuration in Eclipse to your operating system.
5. Build GLUS.

I have all the files for GLUS, but I have not yet linked GLEW and GFLW with eclipse (did it for vc++10 but dont know how in eclipse). So Id need help on that too.

Alternative: why dont I just compile it on VC++10?
Well, I tried and keep getting error C1853 and cant solve it. So im trying to solve the problem by the instructions. >.>

otherwise, if it helps, all the sources are in .c. Any thoughts

Comment: "*Extract this ZIP file*"? What is "this ZIP file?" Also, if the developers of a library can't be bothered to provide a decent build system, then their library isn't worth using. They clearly don't respect your time, so why should you bother using it?

Comment: Amen to that, brother.

Comment: "if the developers of a library can't be bothered to provide a decent build system, then their library isn't worth using. They clearly don't respect your time, so why should you bother using it?" Exactly whats on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the source code archive for GLUS supports CMake so why not just use that? Download the most recent GLUS source available [here](https://github.com/McNopper/GLUS), unzip the source to any directory, and open a terminal / command prompt. Navigate to the directory you extracted the source code to and type `cmake .` (assuming cmake is installed in your system path)

**In Windows**:

CMake will generate a visual studio solution file which you can open with VS and build with F5. If the build is successful, this will generate a glus.lib file in GLUS/Debug. Add this library file to your lib path, and add the src files in /src to your include path.

Now, if your still getting precompiled  header errors (error C1853), select the project node in Solution Explorer, right click, select "Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As". Select "Compile as C Code (/TC)". Additionally you may want to navigate to "Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Precompiled Headers". You can see the option settings here for precompiled headers, which you may want to play with;

**In Unix / Linux / MAC**:

After running cmake type `make all` to build and `sudo make install` to push the generated files into your system path.

Comment: I followed the steps with CMake, and I managed to create the glus.lib. I added this into the lib folder, and I also copied the headers in their respective folders into the include (also added the sources). So, I finally got rid of the C1853 problem, but I am getting two error lnks: `1>glus.lib(glus_glfw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _glewExperimental 
1>glus.lib(glus_log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function _glusLogPrint
` Would you happen to know how to fix this? Regardless, you did answer my first question ^^.

Comment: Did you add glus.lib to your project's linker inputs in VS? If not, right click on your project (in VS) select properties then go to Linker->Inputs and prepend it to the Additional Dependencies.

Comment: Did so, not sure if I have to put all the .obj's someplace?