# How to build GLUS with MinGW and Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, opengl, build, mingw, sublimetext3

I am in a similar situation :
[Eclipse CPP and GNU following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754872/eclipse-cpp-and-gnu-following-these-instructions).  But i need to build GLUS with MinGW and sublime text.

I am learning C and OpenGL ,so i lack compilation/dependencies logic.
I would just like to undertsand in a simple way.

- how to compile GLUS from those source:
  https://github.com/McNopper/OpenGL/tree/master/GLUS/src
- Where to install all the files in MinGW folder to setup things correctly.

Glew and Glfw are already configure correctly and works fine.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Norbert Nopper kindly answer my question directly. And like the answer mention above. The path to follow to compile GLUS without any ide is by using cmake.

> in the GLUS folder, there is a CMake file (https://cmake.org/). With
>   CMake, you can create the GLUS library without any IDE and for a lot
>   of platforms – including Windows and MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Yes cmake is the answer.

You usually create a build directory. Inside your git clone of the repository you do :

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```